# MATLAB implementation for Flexible Least Squares (FLS) regression

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares

Is there a MATLAB implementation for [Flexible Least Squares (FLS) regression](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/tesfatsi/flshome.htm)<sup>1</sup>?

I am looking for a decent (well, the least painful) way to handle regression with time-varying coefficients. All ideas are welcome, but the best would be a pointer to a FLS regression implementation, because I couldn't find one after extensive googling.

---

[<sup>1. R. Kalaba and L. Tesfatsion (1989), *"Time-Varying Linear Regression via Flexible Least Squares"*, Computers and Mathematics with Applications, Vol. 17, pp. 1215-1245</sup>](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/tesfatsi/TimeVaryingLinearReg.CMWA1989.pdf)

Comment: Is there a toy input which I can use to validate my code?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [R code on GitHub](https://github.com/bwlewis/fls/blob/master/R/fls.R) of the FLS regression. I have converted it to MATLAB, but it may have some errors due to differences between the functions of R and MATLAB. Now, we just need to test it in order to do the final adjustments.

```
function X = fls(A, b, mu, ncap, smoothed)

if isempty(mu)
    mu = 1;
end

if isempty(ncap)
    ncap = length(b);
end

if isempty(smoothed)
    smoothed = true;
end

[m n] = size(A);

M = zeros(n, n, ncap);
E = zeros(n, ncap);
X = zeros(n, ncap);
R = eye(n) * mu;

for j = 1:ncap
    Z = linsolve( qr( R + tcrossprod(A(j,:)) ), eye(n) );
    M(:,:,j) = mu * Z;               % (5.7b)
    v = b(j) * A(j,:);

    if (j == 1) 
        p = zeros(n,1);
    else
        p = mu * E(:,j-1);
    end

    w = p + v;

    E(:,j) = Z * w;                  % (5.7c)
    R = -mu * mu * Z;

    diag = R(1:n+1:end);
    R(diag) = R(diag) + 2*mu;
end

% Calculate eqn (5.15) FLS estimate at ncap
Q = -mu * M(:,:,ncap-1);

diag = Q(1: (size(Q,1)+1) : end);
Q(diag) = Q(diag) + mu;
Ancap = A(ncap,:);

C = Q + Ancap' * Ancap;
d = mu * E(:,ncap-1) + b(ncap)*Ancap';
X(:,ncap) = C * d;
X(:,ncap) = linsolve(qr(C),d);

if smoothed
    % Use eqn (5.16) to obtain smoothed FLS estimates for
    % X[,1], X[,2], ..., X[,ncap-1]

    for j = 1:ncap-1
        l = ncap - j;
        X(:,l) = E(:,l) + M(:,:,l) * X(:,l+1);
    end
else
    X = X(:,ncap);
end

end

function resp = tcrossprod(A)
resp = A * A';
end
```

Comment: What are these two lines doing? `diag = Q(1: (size(Q,1)+1) : end);
Q(diag) = Q(diag) + mu;` What if Q is just a 1x1 matrix?

Comment: This line gets the indices of the principal diagonal. I don't have MATLAB on hand to test it now, but if Q is 1x1, I think it will return an empty matrix. If not, it will give an error. To solve this, we should check first the size of Q, if 1x1, then use its single value; else, use this line.